# export more than one class from a single js file

Tags: react-native

so as a new years resolution i have decided to learn a little about react native. For now I am just playing around getting to know it a little. I have this code below, that import the FadeInView or Greeting. If I only have one of these on the exports on the page the remaining one works fine, but when i have them both on the page it just crashes.

I know this is super basic stuff but it's driving me mad, can any one help?

Also can anyone point me in the direction of some good free tutorials for some one starting at zero?

Thanks in advance.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import FadeInView from './components/FadeInView';
import Greeting from './Greeting';



export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <FadeInView style={{width: 250, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 28, textAlign: 'center', margin: 10}}>Fading in</Text>
        </FadeInView>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

export default class LotsOfGreetings extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Greeting name='Rexxar' />
        <Greeting name='Jaina' />
        <Greeting name='Valeera' />
      </View>
    )
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good practice in React/React-Native is to have one component class per file, so you can always export them by default (you can only export default once per file).

By the way, your `LotsOfGreetings` component will never be displayed as your App component don't use it (your entry point is the main component that will wrap all your app, declared by `AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)` at the end of your file).

So i suggest moving your LotsOfGreetings component in another file :

*LotsOfGreetings.js :*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Greeting from './Greeting';

export default class LotsOfGreetings extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Greeting name='Rexxar' />
                <Greeting name='Jaina' />
                <Greeting name='Valeera' />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your App component like this :

*App.js :*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import FadeInView from './components/FadeInView';
import LotsOfGreetings from './LotsOfGreetings';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <FadeInView style={{width: 250, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 28, textAlign: 'center', margin: 10}}>Fading in</Text>
                </FadeInView>
                <LotsOfGreetings />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)
```